# How to trigger wow.js animation when using smooth-scrollbar?

Tags: animation, fadein, smooth-scrolling, wow.js

I am using [smooth-scrollbar](https://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/) on my website along with wow.js animations. But wow animations like fadeinleft, fadein, fadeout etc not working while using smooth scrollbar.

Turning off the smooth scrollbar makes the wow animations work.